# Split string by paired delimiters in Javascript, on multiple occurrences, and with exclusions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to split a string in Javascript by looking for `{}` paired delimiters.

These might occur multiple times in the same string, and be skipped when an antecedent `\` appears or when they spread across new lines `\n`.

The overall string itself is coming from a `txt` file, and the values need to be processed separately.

```
Grab this {value1}, and also this other {value2}.\n
Do not grab this \{value3}, and leave behind {value4 and\n
value5} too.
```

The regexp to use here seems to very very complex for me and I'd really appreciate some help! Here's my first attempt to solve this: https://regex101.com/r/zjtKFp/1

`[^\\]{([^}\n]+)}`

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to replace them? Reason you do not use a string literal?

Comment: @epascarello Great question, I just improved mine to make it a bit clearer. I am looking to replace and process those values, but the string itself is living in an external txt file!

Comment: Showing your attempt at https://regex101.com/ is usually appreciated.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Here's my attempt! https://regex101.com/r/zjtKFp/1 I couldn't get rid of the whitespace before the bracket.

Comment: So your question now boils down on how to avoid the capture of the character that comes before the opening brace?

Comment: @trincot I've been very slowly getting there but, essentially, yes. It'd be also great to know if the regexp can be improved, or if it has any side-effect I might not be aware of!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is going in the right direction. You should not be worried about the extra character that is matched, as you can just deal with the capture group which does not include that character.

There are however still a few shortcomings in your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/zjtKFp/1):

- If the opening brace is the very first character of your input, then it will not be matched.
- If there are *two* backslashes before the opening brace (or by extension: an even number of them), then the brace will also not be matched, while it actually should: the backslash does not escape the brace, but is itself escaped by the backslash that precedes it.
- If there is a line break character different from `\n` (like `\r`), then it is not rejected. You can use the fact that the dot (`.`) does not match line breaks (unless you override that default behaviour).
- If the *closing* brace is escaped with a backslash it should probably not be interpreted as the end of the match... So a similar algorithm would be needed there as with the opening brace.

You could improve on those points with the following regex:

[`(?:[^\\]|^)(?:\\\\)*{(.*?(?=.)[^\\](?:\\\\)*)}`](https://regex101.com/r/zjtKFp/4)

Here is an implementation in JavaScript to demonstrate that with the capture group you can get rid of the extra character:

```js
let s = String.raw`{here}, grab this {value1}, and also this other {value2}.
Do not grab this \{value3}, and leave behind {value4 and
value5} too, and likewise {value6\\\}.`;

let matches = Array.from(
    s.matchAll(/(?:[^\\]|^)(?:\\\\)*{(.*?(?=.)[^\\](?:\\\\)*)}/g), 
    ([_, grp]) => grp
);

console.log(matches);
```

NB: Usually you would escape braces in a regex, as they have a meaning as a quantifier, like in `a{1,3}`, but as they are not used like that in this regex, it works without escaping them.

Comment: Thank you so much for also anticipating all the other issues I would've faced! It might be related to another issue going on, but I am reading the file with `fs.readFile('./file.txt', 'utf8')`. In this case, it seems the `\\` is not excluded by the rexeg. How can I catch it?

Comment: It does not matter how you get the string. Just check what the string looks like before you apply the regex. Make sure what the backslash "situation" is *at the time* you apply the regex. If you have a problem with a specific string, please let me know which string it is.

Comment: It's the _/{value3}_ occurrence I'm having problems with. If I write the entire text inside the `js` file like in your example, the regexp works fine! But if I try to load and process it from an external file with `fs.readFile`, _/{value3}_ is not excluded.

Comment: That just proves that the string is not what you think it is. The history of a string (whether you read it from a file, or input it from a console, or whatever) is not relevant. What is relevant is what the string is *at the moment* you apply the regex. It may help to print the length of the string. One can easily be tricked by the number of backslashes in a string if you misinterpret the debugging results. Printing the length and counting characters can help pinpoint misinterpretations. Note that in your previous comment you have a *forward* slash.

Comment: If you can do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(str))` of your string (as it is after reading it from the file), and give me that information *exactly* as you get it in console from *that* statement, I can try to help find what the issue is you have. Note that this output will double the backslashes because of the JSON format.